# Select specific row when available, if not default

Tags: sql, select, case

I have a table, that gives out specific facility ID information and what source system it came from. The problem I am having is that sometimes the same facility ID appears more than once because it is in multiple source system. But in this case each source system gives a different "complete_facility_id". Like below:

| complete_building_id | facility_id | LTP_facility_id | source_system |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AUC LH | 002216 | 002216 | ONEIL |
| DBHOLT 000DA | 002216 | 002216 | SECUREBASE |

In this case when I ran my query to get all data for facility_id: 002216 both of these rows come since there are two different source systems "ONEIL" and "SECUREBASE". In this case I would want JUST the oneil row.

Now if I were to select a different facility id "003314"

| complete_building_id | facility_id | LTP_facility_id | source_system |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DLT 000DS | 003314 | 003314 | SECUREBASE |

This is fine.

How could I write a query to select everything from this table, and remove any rows when there are duplicates and only keep the oneil rows?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?`

Comment: Why is "ONEIL" more important that "SECUREBASE"? Or is this just a hard-coded definition?

Comment: Which one row?  What criteria do you use to decide?

Comment: If there are no ONEIL row, do you want SECUREBASE or nothing?

Comment: Search for how to get one row per group, there are many hundreds of similar questions, use row_number and order by source_system.

Comment: If there are several ONEIL, do you want all or just one (which one)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL [Window function](https://mode.com/sql-tutorial/sql-window-functions/) to do that

Step 1. Use SQL window function and [rank()](https://mode.com/sql-tutorial/sql-window-functions/#rank-and-dense_rank) to set ONEIL as top-rank result when it exists.When ONEIL exists for a specific facility_id, ONEIL row is rank_num = 1 row; When ONEIL doesn't exists for a specific facility_id, another source_system row will become rank_num = 1

Step 2. Filter data to only show rank_num = 1 result.

See the following as example:

```
WITH table_w_rank_per_facility AS (
SELECT
    complete_building_id,
    facility_id,
    LTP_facility_id,
    source_system,
    rank() over (partition by facility_id order by (case when source_system = 'ONEIL' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) DESC) as rank_num
FROM
  table
)
SELECT
    complete_building_id,
    facility_id,
    LTP_facility_id,
    source_system
FROM
    table_w_rank_per_facility
```